# Find GCD of 2 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is wrong here?

The loop conditions should be fulfilled but the program is not entering the loop.

```
a=100
b=55
c = min(a,b)
while (a % c !=0 // b % c != 0):
    c = c - 1
    gcd = c
print(gcd)
```

EDIT: I'm dumb.

Comment: For your future endeavors: I can't think of any other languages where `//` is "or". Often, it is `|` for "or", and `||` for short-circuit "or". My suspicion is you have confused the two from another language. In Python, `or` always short-circuits.

Answer (score 3):

`//` is the floor division operator. You need to use `or` for the logical OR function. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) is a simple article on basic Python operators.

```py
a=100
b=55
c = min(a,b)
while (a % c !=0) or (b % c != 0):
    c = c - 1
    gcd = c
print(gcd) # prints 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly what you're asking about, but the far more efficient way to compute the gcd is with the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Also, `gcd = c` does not need to be inside the while loop.

Here's some alternative code.

```
a = 100
b = 55

while b != 0:
    a, b = b, a % b
gcd = a
print(gcd)
```